# PDO inserindo null

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Estou tentando criar uma tela simples de cadastro de usuários, mas estou com problemas ao realizar o `insert`. O método é executado mas o `MySQL` insere `null` em vez dos campos do formulário que eu obtenho através de um `foreach`, podem me dizer aonde estou errando?

Estou usando Conexão PDO.

**`Usuario.php`**

```
<?php
    Class Usuario{

    private $id_login;
    private $usuario;
    private $senha;
    private $status;
    private $nome;
    private $sobrenome;


    public function __construct(){ 

        // 
    } 

    public function getId_login(){
    return $this->id_login;

    }

    public function setId_login($id_login){
    return $this->id_login = $id_login;

    }

    public function getUsuario(){
    return $this->usuario;

    }

    public function setUsuario($usuario){
    return $this->usuario = $usuario;

    }

    public function getSenha(){
    return $this->senha;

    }

    public function setSenha($senha){
    return $this->senha = $senha;

    }

    public function getStatus(){
    return $this->status;

    }

    public function setStatus($status){
    return $this->status = $status;

    }

    public function getNome(){
    return $this->nome;
    }

    public function setNome($nome){  
    return $this->nome = $nome;

    }
    public function getSobrenome(){
    return $this->sobrenome;
    }

    public function setSobrenome($sobrenome){  
    return $this->sobrenome = $sobrenome;}


} // fim da classe usuario

?>
```

**`usuario_crud.php`**

```
<?php

        Class Usuario_crud{

        public static $conexaoPDO;

        // Instanciando a conexao  e a classe
        public function __construct(){

        $this->conexaopdo = Conexao::getConexao();


     } public function Inserir(Usuario $usuario){

        try{ 

            // variavel recebendo a consulta

            $insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_login_admin (
                        usuario,
                        senha,
                        nome,
                        sobrenome)
                        VALUES(
                        :usuario,
                        :senha,
                        :nome,
                        :sobrenome)";

                        // abrindo a classe de conexão PDO

                        $prepare_sql = $this->conexaopdo->prepare($insert);

                        // repassando parametros através de bindParam
                        $prepare_sql->bindValue(":usuario", $usuario->getUsuario());
                        $prepare_sql->bindValue(":senha", $usuario->getSenha());
                        $prepare_sql->bindValue(":nome", $usuario->getNome());
                        $prepare_sql->bindValue(":sobrenome", $usuario->getSobrenome());

                        // executando a instrução
                         return $prepare_sql->execute();    


            } // fim do try

            catch (Exception $e) {
                Echo " $e Ocorreu um erro ao tentar executar essa Inclusão de Dados, Tente novamente mais tarde
                ou contato o administrador do Sistema";

             }

            } // fim da function Insert

?>
```

// aqui e aonde percorro os campos do formulário através do foreach para repassar ao metodo Insert

```
<?php

      if (isset($_POST['cadastrar'])){

            //laço que percorre os campos para obter os dados digitados no HTML através da Funçao $_POST
            foreach ($_POST as $campo => $valor) {
            $$campo = post($campo);
           }

              // instanciando a classe usuario.
              $user = new Usuario();

              // instanciando a classe usuario crud
              $user_crud = new Usuario_crud();


              // iniciando o metodo de Inserir
              $user_crud->inserir($user, $campo);



      } // fim do if   


?>
```

Comment: você viu que `$$campo = post($campo);` tem 2 `$`?

Comment: Em lugar nenhum você setou as propriedades do objeto `$user`. Também não faz muito sentido um método `set()` retornar valor. `public static $conexaoPDO;` não parece ser usado para nada no código.

Comment: olá amigo, respondendo seu questionamento, eu vi sim que a variável $$campo tem 2 $$ .. então na verdade como ela está no loop dessa forma ela obtém automaticamente os campos name do html, se voce olhar no foreach ai eu tenho uma função que retira os '' do campo.. sobre a parte do conexaopdo é ela q inicia, se eu tirar esse trecho do codigo o insert não funciona. obrigado pela ajuda.. pessoal! agora tá ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem algumas coisas estranhas nesse códigos, o principal problema é não popular o objeto `$user`, as chamadas dos `set()` devem tem algum valor que vem do formulário no exemplo usei valores fixos.

```
$user_crud = new Usuario_crud();

$user = new Usuario();
$user->setUsuario('fulano');
$user->setSenha('123');
$user->setNome('fulano da silva');
//demais sets ...

$user_crud->inserir($user);
```

Veja que na assinatura o método inserir define apenas um parâmetro e na chamada são passado dois argumentos.

Declaração:

```
Class Usuario_crud{
   //código omitideo 
   public function Inserir(Usuario $usuario){
```

Chamada:

```
$user_crud->inserir($user, $campo); //esse $campo não deve estar aí
```

A ideia de métodos set é apenas atribuir um valor (externo) a um propriedade (interna) do objeto não faz muito sentido ele ter um return salva em execeções.

```
public function setStatus($status){
   return $this->status = $status;
}
```

Qual a finalidade de `$conexaoPDO`? Um detalhe sutil está no costrutor uma proprieade (`conexaopdo`) é criada de forma dinâmica que significa se o constutor falhar ou deixar de ser usado ela nunca vai existir logo sua conexão falhará, nesse caso é melhor definir essa propriedade no corpo da classe.

```
Class Usuario_crud{
    public static $conexaoPDO;

    public function __construct(){
      $this->conexaopdo = Conexao::getConexao();
    }

//demais códigos
```

Comment: mesmo com isso, creio que não em muito vai ajudar. o ideal seria ele deixar de usar o `PDO` com classes, e usar simplesmente o `mysqli` e funções.

Comment: obrigado amigo! era esse mesmo o problema não estava passando o parâmetro pro objeto ai não tava gravando no banco! (tava apanhando rs.. sou novo em php) agora funcionou..Sobre a conexão Pdo eu tenho uma classe de conexão e chamo ela por lá (eu nao tinha postado ela aqui..)  se eu tirar ela do _construct ai recebo erro ao fazer o insert, mas vou seguir sua dica e colocar ela no corpo da classe, muito obrigado pela ajuda! complementando, se achar necessário eu posto a classe aqui de conexão obrigado